# What's the proper way to use an unattached send method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

In the process of developing my own library, I've been reading various Ruby libraries on Github for understanding common idioms.  One library I've been referencing ([found here](https://github.com/paulsingh/angellist-api/blob/master/lib/angellist_api/api.rb)), leverages what I'd call an "unattached send method".  Here's the code:

```
module AngellistApi
    class API

        attr_accessor *Configuration::VALID_OPTIONS_KEYS

        # Creates a new API
        def initialize(options={})
          options = AngellistApi.options.merge(options)
          Configuration::VALID_OPTIONS_KEYS.each do |key|
            send("#{key}=", options[key])
          end 
        end
    end  
end
```

All documentation I can find online regarding the send method in Ruby, describes it as a way of calling a method of an object via a string or symbol.  However all examples have the send method attache to the object, e.g.:

```
object.send(:method_name, argument1)
```

What happens when it isn't attached to an object?  In this case is it calling the methods for the class that it's called within?  Can someone explain this code for me? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it occurs inside an instance method, the implied object here is `self`.

```
# create a new object, assigning "foo = bar" given that
# foo is in VALID_OPTIONS_KEYS
object = AngellistApi::API.new({:foo => 'bar'})

# this would essentially do the same thing again
object.send("foo=", "bar")

# (which is equivalent to)
object.foo = bar
```

Comment: Ah duh ... I missed the = component in the send key ... brilliant ... thanks!

Comment: One quick question ... I'm assuming those variables become instance variables at that point?

Comment: In this case yes, as the class defines a bunch of attr_accessors based on the valid option keys.  If you passed `:foo => 'bar'` as I did in the example and `foo` was a valid key, then you'd end up with a `@foo` instance variable on the object.  If `foo` was not a valid key, then you're going to get a `NoMethodError` when trying to initialize the object with it.

Answer (score 2):

"Unattached" isn't the correct term, it's a method call without an *explicit receiver*, and so instead it uses the *implicit receiver*, which is `self`. So `send(:foo)` (implicit receiver) is equivalent to `self.send(:foo)` (explicit receiver). This is not unique to `send`, and is true of any method call.

The only time this equivalency isn't strictly true is when the method called is private, since private methods cannot be called with an explicit receiver (this is, in fact, the definition of private in Ruby).

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, in Ruby when a method is called without an explicit receiver, the implicit receiver is `self`. `self` can sometimes be slippery though -- understanding what `self` is in various contexts is an important and enlightening step in the path to Ruby mastery :-)  Yehuda Katz has [a nice article](http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/15/metaprogramming-in-ruby-its-all-about-the-self/) on the subject, and there are [many others](http://sidtalk.wordpress.com/2008/10/06/what-exactly-is-ruby-self/) out there.

I think [the Pry alternative REPL](https://rubygems.org/gems/pry) can be helpful for exploring. A sample session where the AngelList API lib was loaded:

```
[1] pry(main)> cd AngellistApi::API
[2] pry(AngellistApi::API):2> self
=> AngellistApi::API
[3] pry(AngellistApi::API):2> ls
Object.methods: yaml_tag
AngellistApi::API#methods: access_token  access_token=  adapter  adapter=  connection_options  connection_options=  endpoint  endpoint=  gateway  gateway=  proxy  proxy=  user_agent  user_agent=
locals: _  _dir_  _ex_  _file_  _in_  _out_  _pry_  binding_impl_method
```

Here you can see the accessors that were defined as a result of `attr_accessor *Configuration::VALID_OPTIONS_KEYS`.

Comment: Of course, in an unadorned `initialize` method, `self` is most likely the object being initialized.

Comment: Yes, thank you, probably the most important detail to answer the question and I omitted it! As a contributor to the gem in question I can also say that I think this example is a fairly gross abuse of metaprogramming anyway, enumerating the accessors would be a fine opportunity to actually document what each config option is for... The code for this gem was originally largely ripped from the Twitter gem at the time, IIRC.